# How to cache Fragment data when I switch it in FragmentTabHost

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment-tab-host

When I used FragmentTabHost, and use its manager four fragment and every fragment I customized an ActionBar.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if(rootView==null){
        initActionBar();
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.framelayout_message, null);
    }else{
        ((ViewGroup)rootView.getParent()).removeView(rootView);
    }
    return rootView;
}
public void initActionBar() {
    View abi = getLayoutInflater(null).inflate(R.layout.titlebar_mainmessage, null);
    ButterKnife.inject(this, abi);
    mRgTitle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    actionBar.setCustomView(abi);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
}
```

In every fragment's `onCreateView` method I used same way, but now when I switch tab, the content view will switch but the `ActionBar` can not do it. How should I do it?

I only want to switch tab and not reload data.

Comment: do you want to call `initActionBar` when you switch tab ?

Comment: thanks you remind me , now I call initActionBar when I switch tab,and now the actionBar will change with switch action,But the data will reload also!

Comment: are you attaching fragment each time you switch the tab ?

Comment: I am not listener tab switch action , so the FragmentTahHost would manager their switch action,and I watch FragmentTabHost Src code and when tabChange it will call accach method